# Does ActiveMQ Artemis / RedHat AMQ not set JMS Message ID correctly?

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis, amq

According to the JMS spec, I do not have to specify the message ID when sending.

When I send a message via `JMSProducer#send()` or when I create a message via the hawt.io console, I can see the message ID being set to some internal sequential number generated by the Artemis broker.

However, when I use `MessageConsumer#receive()` or `MessageListener#onMessage()` to receive a `Message`, `Message#getJMSMessageID()` always returns `null`.

The only way I can receive a message with a non-null JMS message ID is by reading a message from a different (IBM) message queue and copying all its properties to the Artemis message before sending it.

I have tested this with both AMQ 7.3.0.GA and Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.6.2, with both native (org.apache.activemq.artemis-jms-client) and AMQP (org.apache.qpid.qpid-jms-client) clients.

Is there some configuration I must set on the broker to make it populate JMS message IDs correctly?

Comment: Can you provide the client code you've tested with? I just ran a simple test with AMQ 7.3.0 by modifying the "queue" example (at examples/features/standard/queue) to print the JMS message ID after the message is sent and when it is received and everything worked as expected (i.e. the message ID was not null).

Comment: @JustinBertram The problem was the Qpid and Core client store the ID in different headers, while the management console doesn't populate it at all.

Comment: The wording of your question doesn't make it clear that you're sending with one protocol and receiving with a different protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. JMS Message ID is usually stored in a native Artemis header that is called userID
2. Messages sent via the management console *do not* populate userID
3. Messages sent via the Core JMS client *do* populate the message ID
4. Messages sent via the Qpid client populate a custom property NATIVE_MESSAGE_ID with the JMS message ID
5. There's no way to obtain the internal message ID via JMS
6. If you send a message via Qpid and read it via Core client or vice versa you will receive a null JMS message ID